# Schengen (Germany) tourist entry for American with felony conviction

Tags: schengen, germany, us-citizens, criminal-records

An American friend of mine wants to visit me in Germany. She is worried because she has prior felony convictions in the U.S. and was previously denied entry to Canada.

Specifically, she was convicted in 1996 of a violent crime and served about 2 months of jail time. She was also convicted of a minor offence as a juvenile in the 1970s.

She attempted to visit Canada in 2015 and was subjected to enhanced scrutiny. During the entry interview she was asked about the convictions and eventually denied entry.

Will these old convictions, or the denial at the Canadian border, prevent my friend from entering Germany? What steps could be taken before travel to improve her chances?

Comment: @Traveller Maybe it does. I'm not sure if the Canadian refusal complicates things. From reading about ETIAS I also had the impression there may be more specific criteria regarding acceptable vs. unacceptable histories. But I don't really know. In any case, I appreciate the link!

Comment: If your friend is really worried that her record may lead to a denial of entry at the border, the advice is generally to get pre-clearance by applying for a visa. Still doesn’t *guarantee* entry but makes denial at the border vanishingly less likely

Comment: @TypeIA ETIAS is not yet in operation.  The official site is https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en and currently says "ETIAS is currently not in operation and no applications are collected at this point."  It is now expected to start in 2024, with no more precise date or even month having been announced.  The start date has been delayed several times, however, so it can be delayed yet again.

Comment: @Traveller It is for visa-exempt citizens not possible to apply for a visa for the Schengen area.